# Toggle all except one and then toggle the excepted one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this Q&A section.

What I want to do is show the clicked one and hide the all others. After that if I click again on the clicked one it will hide like others.

I have done the hide all parts except the 2nd click part.

### MARKUP

```
<h4 class=" question"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus faq_icon"></span><strong>How r u?</strong></h4>
            <p class="answer">Fine</p>

            <h4 class=" question"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus faq_icon" id=""></span><strong>What r u doing?</strong></h4>
            <p class=" answer">nothing.</p>
```

### JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".question").click(function() {
        $('.answer').not(this).hide();
        $(this).next(".answer").toggle();
    });
});
```

Now I need to hide the `THIS` on 2nd click. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the current `answer` element to `not()`.

`this` in the click handler is the `question` element so `$('.answer').not(this).hide();` will hide all the `answer` elements, then calling `toggle` for the current answer element will always display it instead of toggling it

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".question").click(function() {
    var $ans = $(this).next(".answer").toggle();
    $('.answer').not($ans).hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.answer {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4 class=" question"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus faq_icon"></span><strong>How r u?</strong></h4>
<p class="answer">Fine</p>
<h4 class=" question"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus faq_icon" id=""></span><strong>What r u doing?</strong></h4>
<p class=" answer">nothing.</p>
```

Comment: Your code is ok but I need to show the answer at first.

Comment: @ZahidulIslamSuzon just remove the css rule `.answer {
  display: none;
}`

Comment: [first ? 'show' : 'toggle']();

can you please explain this part :)

Comment: @ZahidulIslamSuzon As you can see `first` is a boolean variable, if that is true then we are calling `show` method... else the toggle method... the `? :` construct is the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), the `['string']` is the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation)

Comment: @ZahidulIslamSuzon a more readable format could be https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hotv78xk/3/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102214/discussion-between-zahidul-islam-suzon-and-arun-p-johny).

Answer (score 1):

Check it

```
$(".question").click(function() {
    $('.answer').hide();
    if(!$(this).next(".answer").is(':visible')) {
        $(this).next(".answer").show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(".question").click(function() {
    if( $(this).is(':visible') ){
        $('.answer').not(this).hide();
    }else {
         $('.answer').hide();
    }
    $(this).next(".answer").toggle();
```

});